# Ruby can't convert Array to Integer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm getting this error:

```
TypeError in Properties#show
```

At line #67 in /Users/taylor/Pro/rentroll_analysis/app/views/properties/show.html.erb, where this exception is raised:

```
can't convert Array into Integer
```

This is the extracted source around line #67:

```
64:     <td><%=u.unit_number%></td>
65:     <td><%=u.unit_type%></td>
66:     <td><%=number_to_currency(u.market_rent - u.current_rent)%></td>
67:     <td><%=number_to_currency(u.market_rent - u.current_rent)*(session[:assumptions]=    [:spread_x])%></td>
68:    
69:   </tr>
70: <%end%>
```

When running this:

```
def setup_assumptions
  if session[:assumptions].nil?
    session[:assumptions]=[:min_spread=>400,:spread_x=>10]
  end
end
```

I'm sure it's relatively simple but I can't figure it out.

Comment: Please tag your question with the language you're using so that people who know that language will spot your question.

Comment: The equal sign really confused me.

Answer (score 1):

If you're trying to set it to a map, use a map (curly braces) not an array (square brackets):

```
session[:assumptions] = { :min_spread => 400, :spread_x => 10 }
```

Otherwise you're setting `session[:assumptions]` to an array with a hash *in* it.

Also, what is your goal here?

```
number_to_currency(u.market_rent - u.current_rent) * (session[:assumptions]= [:spread_x])
```

I think you mean:

```
number_to_currency(u.market_rent - u.current_rent) * session[:assumptions][:spread_x]
```

Comment: can't convert Symbol into Integer

Comment: basically i am using array to list assumptions. I want to multiply the (u.market_rent-u.current_rent) by 10

Comment: @user1902953 What are "array to list assumptions"?

Answer (score 0):

When you save something to your session it saves it as a string, so when you're pulling something back from the session and want to perform Integer methods on it, you'll likely have to specify that it's an integer.

Doing something like: `session[:assumptions][:spread_x].to_i` to use your session content as an integer. Also, please note I think you have an errant `=` in your original code.

Lastly, you might not run into this, but I've sometimes had trouble using nested symbols in session variables. As in `session[:assumptions][:spread_x]`. I've sometimes had to change this to something like `session[:assumptions]['spread_x']` and call the nested variable with a string instead.

Good luck!